# Writing to Console and File in Python Script

Tags: python, file, console, output

I am looking for some help on a project I am doing where I need to output the responses to the console as well as write them to a file. I am having trouble figuring that part out. I have been able to write the responses to a file successfully, but not both at the same time. Can someone help with that portion? The only lines that need to be written to the file are the ones that I have currently being written to a file

```
from datetime import datetime
import requests
import pytemperature


def main():
    api_start = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='
    api_key = '&appid=91b8698c2ed6c192aabde7c9e75d23cb'
    now = datetime.now()

    filename = input("\nEnter the output filename: ")
    myfile = None
    try:
        myfile = open(filename, "w")
    except:
        print("Unable to open file " + filename +
              "\nData will not be saved to a file")

    choice = "y"

    print("ISQA 3900 Open Weather API", file=myfile)
    print(now.strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y"), file=myfile)

    while choice.lower() == "y":
        # input city and country code
        city = input("Enter city: ")
        print("Use ISO letter country code like: https://countrycode.org/")
        country = input("Enter country code: ")

        # app configures url to generate json data
        url = api_start + city + ',' + country + api_key
        json_data = requests.get(url).json()

        try:
            # getting weather data from json
            weather_description = json_data['weather'][0]['description']

            # printing weather information
            print("\nThe Weather Report for " + city + " in " + country + " is:", file=myfile)
            print("\tCurrent conditions: ", weather_description, file=myfile)

            # getting temperature data from json
            current_temp_kelvin = json_data['main']['temp']
            current_temp_fahrenheit = pytemperature.k2f(current_temp_kelvin)

            # printing temperature information
            print("\tCurrent temperature in Fahrenheit:", current_temp_fahrenheit, file=myfile)

            # getting pressure data from json
            current_pressure = json_data['main']['pressure']

            # printing pressure information
            print("\tCurrent pressure in HPA:", current_pressure, file=myfile)

            # getting humidity data from json
            current_humidity = json_data['main']['humidity']

            # printing humidity information
            print("\tCurrent humidity:", "%s%%" % current_humidity, file=myfile)

            # getting expected low temp data from json
            expected_low_temp = json_data['main']['temp_min']
            expected_low_temp = pytemperature.k2f(expected_low_temp)

            # printing expected low temp information
            print("\tExpected low temperature in Fahrenheit:", expected_low_temp, file=myfile)

            # getting expected high temp data from json
            expected_high_temp = json_data['main']['temp_max']
            expected_high_temp = pytemperature.k2f(expected_high_temp)

            # printing expected high temp information
            print("\tExpected high temperature in Fahrenheit:", expected_high_temp, file=myfile)

            choice = input("Continue (y/n)?: ")
            print()

        except:
            print("Unable to access ", city, " in ", country)
            print("Verify city name and country code")

    if myfile:
        myfile.close()
    print('Thank you - Goodbye')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Honestly I am kind of at a loss on this one for some reason it is just kicking my butt.

Comment: write your own `print(..)` function that does both...?

Comment: What would that sort of print statement look like? Do you have an example by chance?

Comment: What happens when you try to do both, and is that part of your current code?

Answer (score 0):

For printing a single object:

```
def mprint(text, file):
    print(text)
    print(text, file = file)
```

A more general one for printing several objects:

```
def mprint(*args):
   print(*args[:-1])
   print(*args[:-1],file = args[-1])
```

Usage: mprint(obj1, obj2, ... , myfile)

Comment: What would that look like added to some of the code that I have provided?

Comment: Just add the 2nd function definition before or inside your main() function, then replace all the print statements where you want to write both on file and console with mprint (but for the last argument, write myfile instead of file=myfile).

Answer (score 0):

A completely general print function replacement would look something like:

```
def myprint(*args, file=None, **kwargs):
    print(*args, **kwargs)            # print to screen
    if file is not None:
        print(*args, file=fp, **kwargs)   # print to file
```

this will let you use `end=..` etc. as well

```
    filename = input("\nEnter the output filename: ")
    myfile = None
    try:
        myfile = open(filename, "w")
    except:
        print("Unable to open file " + filename +
              "\nData will not be saved to a file")

    choice = "y"

    myprint("ISQA 3900 Open Weather API", file=myfile)
    myprint(now.strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y"), file=myfile)
```

if `myfile` couldn't be opened and is therefore `None`, the `myprint` function will only print to screen.